# Would it be a problem to ask the question of historical proof of the existence of the controversial St. Philomena?

Tags: discussion, catholicism

**Would it be  a problem to ask the question of historical proof of the existence of the controversial [St. Philomena](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philomena) within the Catholic Church?**

I realize that this subject matter could upset some individuals on the main site such as follows:

- [Who is the oldest Blessed?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4751/who-is-the-oldest-blessed)
- [Can Patron Saints be “dethroned”?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/60457/can-patron-saints-be-dethroned)

In order to limit individuals from getting upset, I would limit the question to historical data (with archeological interpretations from competent sources), papal declarations and/or teachings. Individual interpretations would also be eliminated in any responses.

Visions of Catholic visionaries or mystics would be excluded because they are not historical data open to various interpretations.

Personal reflections would not be included.

If anyone think the question should be limited or expanded somehow, please let me know, as I am open to suggestions in this domain.

Comment: I think it would be fine. There's fifteen centuries between her claimed life and when the tomb was discovered. But if you're going for a historical question, should papal declarations really be included?

Comment: @curiousdannii My goal would be to show that no cult exists for the reasons for a canonical canonization, so perhaps you are correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can put whatever limits you want on the question.  You can even frame the question, "as a Swedenborgian, prove to me your Philomena" if you wanted.

However, I wouldn't specifically exclude personal reflections  and Catholic visionaries.

Personal reflections obviously can't make up the basis of any answer but I absolutely hate removing them from answers because they make up the color of the site and separate us from the baseness of a wiki.

And Catholic visionaries oftentimes actually make up the basis for what is discovered to be true.  So if one had to remove the prophecy from the reality you'd be left with just a naked reality; denuded of supernatural truth.

Comment: The problem of visions is that it is not a recognized source of historical or archeological value. Some use visions as a source of primary input. Especially in this case as the scientific proofs are not numerous!